# smallest simplest $E_8$ -module 

Tags: exceptional-groups, lie-algebras, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

What is the smallest simplest(non-trivial) $E_8$ -module ?

Comment: $\mathbb C\ \ \ $

Comment: I agree with Hassan; the smallest simplest $E_8$-module is actually $(0)$.

Comment: Hassan's question combined with his comment makes the whole thing look trivial indeed.  Anyway, the smallest *faithful* representations of all simple Lie algebras are worked out in the old literature and not very hard to relate to the fundamental weights.    What is the point of the question?   (And why the extra tags?)

Comment: Dear @Jim Humphreys, If possible for you, please add some open access online links in your comments 

Comment: This is somewhat beside the point, but the difference between Allen Knutson's and Robert Bryant's answers seems to hinge on whether the word "simple" is meant in a strict mathematical sense.  Since $(0)$ is a unit under direct sum, it is often more convenient to adopt the convention that it is a non-simple module.

Comment: Zuckerman calls these "the trivial representation" and "the pre-trivial representation".

Comment: Dear @ Allen Knutson Thanks for your comment , it was useful  

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cartan showed that the lowest dimensional (nontrivial) $E_8$-module is ${\frak{e}}_8$ itself, i.e., the adjoint representation, which has dimension $248$.  The next smallest nontrivial irreducible module is considerably larger dimension, $3875$, and I think that the next one after that has dimension $30380$.

At 
http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/form.html, you can check these online using LiE.

Comment: like always very niceeeeeeee

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mu(L)$ denote the minimal dimension of a faithful module of $L$. The complex
simple Lie algebra $E_8$ satisfies $\mu(L)=\dim (L)$, as Cartan showed. Indeed, $E_8$
is the *only* complex simple Lie algebra with this property. There are more results in this
direction (which are perhaps interesting):
suppose that $L$ is a complex
semisimple Lie algebra satisfying $\mu(L)=\dim (L)$. Then $L\simeq E_8\oplus \cdots \oplus E_8$. Even more general, let $L$ be a Lie algebra, where the solvable radical $rad(L)$
is abelian. Then always $\mu(L)\le \dim (L)$, and equality holds if and only if $L$ is 
abelian of dimension less than $5$, or $L$ is isomorphic to $E_8\oplus \cdots \oplus E_8$.
(For references see arXiv:1006.2062).

Comment: niceeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: @Hassan, there is very little need to use so many es.

Comment: Dear Mariano, Yes, I believe to your comment. 

Comment: In a sense, the smallest thing you could study in order to study $E_8$ is $E_8$ itself. :)